# How would I find a specific value from a request/text (python)?

Tags: python

I want to find the value "cachedAt" from data from a URL but how would I get JUST the value for "cachedAt" and not the entire text?.

[Request I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldyaZ.png)
[Value I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFzIX.png)

I'm new to getting these things so sorry if it seems simple.

I tried using beautiful soup to grab it but it's in

and whenever I added and id to find(the cachedAt), it would return blank for no matter WHAT id I put(any letter, word, symbol, ext).

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: as @MichaelButscher says. Also: REST APIs usually return JSON data, which can easily be deserialized into a python dictionary. That would be the way to go, but without more code information it is hard to say exactly...

Answer (score 1):

cachedAt is a top-level key in the JSON response. So (using a sample locationId):

```
import requests

URL = "https://www.virail.bg/api/weather"
PARAMS = {
    "locationId": "a.2907703"
}
with requests.get(URL, params=PARAMS) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.json()["cachedAt"])
```